# How do you install and use grails test coverage?

Tags: grails, plugins, code-coverage

I'm trying to get the grails code coverage plugin to work based on these directions:
http://www.grails.org/Test+Code+Coverage+Plugin

I did: grails install-plugin code-coverage

Then: grails test-app

Based on that I expect to see a tests/report/cobertura directory, but I don't see anything inside my project after running "grails test-app".

I've got grails 1.1 installed and created a new application. Do I need to do anything else to see these reports? Are there better instructions anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use "grails test-app -coverage" to generate the coverage reports.

Comment: Any ideas on how to turn this on by default?

Comment: **Config.groovy**

coverage {
 enabledByDefault = true
}